# Differential form of the arclength of a unit circle

Tags: real-analysis

For the unit circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$, the arclength using differential form notation is given as
$$
ds = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~~\text{for}~~0\leq x \leq1.
$$

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along a curve you can approximate the arclength as $\Delta s^2 = \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2$ using Pythagorean theorem. In the limit the approximation becomes exact and you have $ds^2 = dx^2+dy^2$. If you treat $y$ as a function of $x$ (this requires some conditions which are satisfied for the circle, *locally*), then
$$
ds^2 = dx^2(1+y'^2)\Longrightarrow ds = dx\sqrt{1+y'^2}
$$
In your case, locally either
$y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so $y'^2= x^2/1-x^2$. Therefore
$$
ds = dx\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}= \frac{ dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For a function defined by $y(x)$, the arc length is equal to $$s^\prime(x)=\sqrt{1+(y^\prime(x))^2}.$$

Here $$y(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}, \ y^\prime(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ (for the upper part of the circle).

Hence $$s^\prime(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$